# Show API JSON response data in Angular 4 front-end application

Tags: angular

I am trying to connect my angular 4 app with backend api and getting response as and json object. Now want to show this json response to front end.
Please check below json which i am getting in response-

```
{
    "languages": [
        {"1": "Hindi"},
        {"2": "English"},
        {"3": "Metallica"}
    ],
    "status": "200"
}
```

where languages tag is an json array and i want to show it in select option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwW50.png)

Please suggest

Comment: Hi Guys, please check the correct one response which i am getting.
{
 "languages":[{"name":"Hindi","id":"1"},{"name":"English","id":"2"},{"name":"Metallica","id":"3"}],
 "status":"200"
}

Comment: Please check the below answer , and also working demo

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the data You can do that by :

```html
<div *ngFor='let language of data?.languages'>
    {{ language | json }}
</div>
```

---

But if you want to show it in proper way

Component side:

```
getKey(el){
    return Object.keys(el)[0];
}

getValue(el){
    return el[this.getKey(el)];
}
```

Template side :

```html
<div *ngFor='let language of data?.languages'>
    {{ getKey(language) }} --> 
    {{ getValue(language) }}
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-show-json-data)**